# Magento configurable products: when customer selects a size "SAVE" it for next product view

Tags: configurable-product

We have a website for fashion. If/when a customer buys shoes or clothing they generally shop ALL products in the same size. And this got me thinking.

When a customer selects size 42 when buying a shirt: Is it possible to "save" this value and when the customer opens the next product the size dropdown is already pre-selected to size 42?

Maybe we should call it a "sticky" attribute

Comment: If you put the information into local storage, you won't transfer it over the internet that often which might be more friendly for the customer. Also what I wonder how does this work with the different size systems all around.. .

Comment: See the answerd. There is an if/else statement .. so it tries to find a match

Answer (score 1):

Hi ShirtsofHolland and welcome to MageOverflow!

Of course this is possible. I would try the following:

1. Create a new customer attribute
2. Implement an observer which listens to `checkout_cart_product_add_after`
3. save the size in the quote_item to the customer attribute
4. Implement a second observer (no clue what to listen) and pre-select the size on product detail page

You can do the same with the session instead of customer attribute for guests.

Comment: Suppose one adds JS to the bottom of product_view. Bind a set cookie action to the onchange event of the configurable product dropdown. Onpage load try and find the cookie; if found detect if the read value exists in the list; if yes set it. Just an idea that I thought of

Comment: Great idea too, you should add this as an answer!

Comment: I was hoping to find some time to build it first ... but yeah I'll add it already

Comment: ps. If there is a sample/basis extension that adds custom cs to the bottom of product_view only with enable/disable in config ... then I think I might quickly create the JS

Comment: See my updated answer. Interested in your expert view. Or add directly to the repository. Thx. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be done simple via JS only

- Suppose one creates a simple extension
- that adds JS to the bottom of product_view
- Bind a set cookie action to the onchange event of configurable product dropdown
- Onpage load try and find the cookie (else exit);

  - if found detect if the read value exists in the list (else exit);
  - if yes try/catch set it (else exit)

Just as an idea ...

**Hoping to write the code in a small extension but if someone feels the need ;P**

- (To perfect it, version 2) You could store the first preferred (based on a count or being first) - the detect if the read value exists would then loop through the options (suppose one sells shoes, shirts and pants - all with different size attribute value sets)

UPDATE: Please find Github extension below to make it work. Beware, I have not extensively tested this. And would appreciate an expert/guru review.

[Download/view: Github extension SNH_sizeselectorproductview](https://github.com/seansan/SNH_sizeselectorproductview)